# Android market tab Effect without fragments

Tags: android

I want to create a tab Activity like the android market.

I have found a tutorial doing it here :  https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

My problem is that i don't want to use fragments (because they are not supported from older that 2.3 android) but activities.Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
public class Activity extends FragmentActivity {
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "categories", "Featured",
            "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
            "Top New Free", "Trending", "Staff choices", "Editor's Choices" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

        // initialize the pagerz
        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the fragments to be paged
     */
    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag3.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag4.class.getName()));

        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, frag0.class.getName()));

        this.mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter2(super
                .getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(1);
        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
        indicator.setCurrentItem(1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use ActionBarSherlock library?

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

With this library you can use fragments and be compatible all the way down to API Level 4 (target 1.6). Of course, fragments behavior is only simulated when running on pre 3.0 versions, but the API is always the same and once running on 3.0 and newest version it uses native fragments instead simulating them.

Fragments are very convenient and makes your activities much more reusable, because they are  self-contained pieces of the whole application "puzzle".